# xslt multiple parameters into javascript

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Im trying to create a function in javascript in xsl which accepts multiple in-parameters. I can not get it to work and get the following error:

```
Code:   0x80020009
Microsoft JScript runtime error
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
line = 37, col = 2 (line is offset from the start of the script block).
Error returned from property or method call.
```

The function looks as follows:

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="jsfuncs">
    <![CDATA[
    function getLineLength (x1,x2,y1,y2)
    {
    var xVector = x2 - x1;
    var yVector = y2 - y1;
    var output = Math.sqrt(raised2(xVector)+raised2(yVector));
    return output;
    }
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

The calling code looks as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="jsfuncs:getLineLength($x1,$x2,$y1,$y2)"/>
```

x1,x2... are variables set earlier and they are correct. I can get everything to work when I post-process the values to one parameter. Is it at all possible to pass multiple parameters in xslt to Javascript? The engine in use is msxml 3.0.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete code samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Neither have you shown any function `raised2` nor to which value and type you set the variables used in XSLT.

Comment: Ok. But is it even possible and is the current syntax correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example passing in four parameters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ms mf"
    version="1.0">

    <ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="mf">
        function test(a, b, c, d) {
          return a +  ":" + b + ":" + c + ":" + d;
        }
    </ms:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="mf:test(1, 2, 3, 'foo')"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="root/item"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="mf:test(string($item/@a), string($item/@b), string($item/@c), string($item/@d))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, when wanting to pass in a node to a function expecting a primitive value I would recommend to make sure to convert it on the XSLT side to a primitive value first, as done in `mf:test(string($item/@a), string($item/@b), string($item/@c), string($item/@d))`, as otherwise the function will get a node-set represented by some selection interface that you would need to iterate first.

The sample works fine for me with MSXML 3 and outputs `1:2:3:foo<br />1:2:3:whatever` when run against an input sample with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item a="1" b="2" c="3" d="whatever"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. I had to convert the variables (strings) to `number()`.